# Date format in Windows CE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, globalization, date-format

I'm trying to convert the date string to "dd/MM/yyyy" format using the code below

```
m_dEDate = Format(CDate(strExpiry), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

But system got the exception error - "parameter is incorrect". If regional short date is "dd-MMM-yy", there is no exception error.

Without setting regional manually, how could we manage to convert by coding?

Should we use `System.Globalization`? If so, please share me a sample.

Answer (score 1):

use **[`Date.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)**

```
  Dim dateString As String = "06/15/2008"
  Dim format As String = "MM/dd/yyyy"
  Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
  Dim _NewDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider)
```

Comment: oh i forgot it, it should be `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Given the original code, it looks like the OP is trying to *format* the date in `MM/dd/yyyy`, *after* parsing it from some other format (which we don't know about). Either that or the lack of coffee so far this morning is kicking in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to change the format of a date representation, but you haven't told us what format you're converting *from*. John's code shows correctly how to parse a value - but it looks like that's the *target* value you want. Suppose your input is something like "2012-11-15", i.e. yyyy-MM-dd. Then you'd want:

```
Dim inputText = "2012-11-15"
Dim inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
Dim outputFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
Dim provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
Dim parsedDate = Date.ParseExact(inputText, inputFormat, provider)
Dim outputDate = parsedDate.ToString(outputFormat, provider)
```

Note that the use of the invariant culture here isolates you *completely* from culture sensitivity. Is that actually what you want, or do you perhaps want to treat your *input* according to the user culture, but not the output?